# ServiceExceptionHandler usage on RestServiceBase<T>

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to use the `ServiceExceptionHandler` on my Serivce which extends `RestServiceBase<TViewModel>`

I can use the `AppHost.ServiceExceptionHandler`, that's working fine. I need the user info from the `HttpRequest`, thats not available at AppHost level.

So I'm trying to use the `ServiceExceptionHandler` on Service level. Though I set the delegate on service `ctor`, it's `null` when exception thrown on `OnGet` method

```cs
public class StudentService : RestServiceBase<Student>
{ 
    public StudentService()
    {
        ServiceExceptionHandler = (request, exception) =>
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("{0} - {1} \n Request : {2}\n", HttpRequest.UserName(), exception.Message, request.Dump()), exception);
            var errors = new ValidationErrorField[] { new ValidationErrorField("System Error", "TODO", "System Error") };
            return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse("System Error", "System Error", errors);
        };
    }
}
```

I'm not sure of what is the issue with this code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Register Global AppHost.ServiceExceptionHandler

In your `AppHost.Configure()` you can register a global Exception handler with:

```
this.ServiceExceptionHandler = (request, ex) => {
   ... //handle exception and generate your own ErrorResponse
};
```

For finer-grained Exception handlers you can override the following custom service event hooks:

#### Handling Exceptions with the New API

If you're using the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) you can override the Exception by providing a custom runner, e.g:

```
public class AppHost { 
  ...
    public virtual IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(
        ActionContext actionContext)
    {           
        //Cached per Service Action
        return new ServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext); 
    }
}

public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T> {
    public override object HandleException(
        IRequestContext requestContext, TRequest request, Exception ex) {
      // Called whenever an exception is thrown in your Services Action
    }
}
```

#### Handling Exceptions with the Old API

`RestServiceBase<T>` is uses the old API in which you can handle errors by overriding the **HandleException** method, e.g:

```
public class StudentService : RestServiceBase<Student>
{ 
    ...

    protected override object HandleException(T request, Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);

        return base.HandleException(request, ex);
    }
}
```