# With ServiceStack, can I add a log reference all error responses?

Tags: exception, error-handling, customization, servicestack

I've implemented logging of all requests/responses using (in my AppHost.cs):

```cs
this.RequestFilters.Add(serviceLogFilter.LogRequest);
this.ResponseFilters.Add(serviceLogFilter.LogResponse);
```

During the logging of the request, I get the new ID from the logging table and put it into `IHttpRequest.Items`.

My question is: when an error occurs, like if the validation of the incoming data fails, or my business logic throws an Exception, is there a way I can customize the returned error to contain my log reference? Preferably by adding a JSON body to the error response. Alternatively, setting a custom HTTP header?

The idea is that my customer could give me a log reference if something unexcpected happens, and I would find his request and could easily reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question on different ways to Handle exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13058304/85785) from the old and [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api).

To use the `IHttpRequest.Items` dictionary to pass data between request filters, services and response filters in the same request.

Also the [InMemoryRollingRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Providers/InMemoryRollingRequestLogger.cs) implementation for the [Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) plugin shows another way to be able to log all requests.

Comment: After investigating a bit more, a logging Filter (AppHost.ResponseFilters) will be run also when an Exception occurs in my Service. I can add a log ID there, so that part of the problem is solved. However for validation failures, which I'd also like to log, the response filter is NOT run. I tried creating a custom ServiceRunner but neither HandleException or AfterEachRequest is run when validation fails.